# Dynamic sensor calibration

Tags: embedded, normalization, sensors, calibration

I'm working on a project that requires to measure rotations, so I designed an inductive sensor that is capable of measuring the rotations. To simplify the measurements results, I'm getting an sine wave like signal where every wave is one rotation. This needs to be processed on a small embedded device (in C) so I need to do this on the fly, but I'm getting a bit stuck at the calibration part. For your information the values are roughly between 2100 and 2200 but differ between sensors and environment.

Currently my best solution is to dynamically detect the Min value and the Max value and normalize the incoming data stream accordingly, this works relatively well but over time some outliers will further the range outwards and worsen the calibration.

I've looked at other methods like z-score but I can't seem to find a way to determine an average value of the signal. This is because the rotations can stop for hours (keep measuring the same value) and than continue again. With the moving averages I've tried this will adjust the average from the true average.

My thoughts at the moment are that I need a system that determines the min-max range dynamically but is also capable of scaling inwards instead of just increasing outwards. So is there another method that could work for me that I might have missed or do you have any tips?

Comment: May you skip very slow rotaions? If so, try a high pass filter

Comment: Unfortunately not, most measurements are really slow. I've tried playing around with an FFT to remove the DC component which works really well on a larger dataset but in small windows it didn't really work out.

Comment: Why do you need the min and max values if it's rotation? Wouldn't either one suffice, assuming you always measure at a certain edge on the wave? Why are values at all relevant, don't you just seek to measure the period/frequency?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.